# How to create a Navigation Property that returns IQueryable<T> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern, entity-framework-6

My project uses Entity Framework 6 with Repository & UnitOfWork patterns to communicate with a MSSQL database. all configurations are done with Code First.

All of the navigation properties of the Entity Objects are defined for lazy loading as such:

```
public virtual ICollection<> Items  { get; set; }
```

this works well, and the performance is pretty good in most cases. in some cases, however, where the navigation properties refer to a large sets of data, loading them to memory takes a while, at which point LINQing seem like a bad practice. to improve performance, it would make sense to convert some of them to IQueryable<> but EF doesn't seem to accept that kind of configuration.

So although i could workaround this by "Querying" the repositories, in some cases i already have an entity object in memory and it feels right to be able to query its navigation properties without loading all of them, to get the data that i need via LINQ.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You do not. This functionality is not available in Entity Framework. YOu can make a feature request. But right now - no way.